# How can a Django application interact with other python programs running on the same server?

Tags: python, django, web-services, webserver

We have various python applications of varying sizes in our arsenal that provide specific services. What I intend to do is create a website using Django that is able to interact with these other applications in order to provide a web interface to access some features of these external applications and monitor their response. I can handle the Django side well, thanks to their awesome documentation, but I'm somewhat lost when it comes to the big picture. How would  one go about establishing communication with other applications?

**EDIT:**

We also have some programs that aren't written in python, how would Django interact with these?

Comment: In general python programs are treated as packages and modules, like the ones you sometimes encounter within Django (apart from the core django stack), the way you can achieve this is simple include the packages in your python path, then from your Django app you can import them as any other packages `from package.module import foo` just make sure you don't have name conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You need modify those python app you want to communicate. 
There are some tools can do process communication in linux:

```
signal

share memory

file(include tcp socket)

message queue

pipe
```

For python, you can use tcp socket do that, this should be most easy one I guess. But that still depend on what kind data you want to communication.